# flutter error : Execution failed for task ':camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, android-camera

i am trying to use camera plugin in my flutter app
but i am facing this probleme

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

i tried many solution but nothing work for me

here is the gradel.build

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.object"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: for me `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` worked. If it didn't work for you, maybe updating your packages would work : `flutter pub outdate`